# Italian citizenship through grandmother, missing birth certificate

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-citizens, italy, italian-citizens

Below are the documents I need.

> 1. Your maternal grandmother's birth certificate from Italy, also known
>      as an estratto dell'atto di nascita
> 2. Your maternal grandfather's birth certificate
> 3. Your grandparents' marriage certificate (If married outside of Italy,    you will need an apostille and a translation into Italian.)
> 4. Your maternal grandmother's certificate of naturalization OR Italian    passport and permanent resident card/green card (Click here
>      if the    certificate of naturalization is not available.)
> 5. Your mother's birth certificate (with apostille and translation)
> 6. Your father's birth certificate
> 7. Your parents' marriage certificate (with apostille and translation)
> 8. Your birth certificate (with apostille and translation)
> 9. Your marriage certificate, if applicable (with apostille and    translation)
> 10. Your spouse's birth certificate, if applicable
> 11. Birth certificates for all your children under the age of eighteen,    if applicable (with apostille and translation)
> 12. Any applicable divorce decrees/certificates (with apostille and    translation)
> 13. Death certificates for anyone listed above (with apostille and    translation, if for your mother or grandmother)

Now I can get all of these apart from my grandmas birth certificate. She left for the UK when she was 18(born 1935)after that there was a big earthquake in the village she was from and they lost pretty much everything. Will her birth be recorded anywhere else where I can get a copy? She is still alive if I need her to get any of this info.

I also read that I need my grandfathers documents too even if he wasn't born in Italy. But my grandad(deceased) is Polish and was liberated by the British army from a camp in WW2 so the only documents I can get from him are his original alien card when he came to the UK.

None of my grandparents ever became British Citizens and although my mother has never claimed her Italian Citizenship she has never denounced it. My grandma is alive with an Italian passport will that be enough when going to the Italian consulate without her birth certificate or will I be denied? €300 isn't the end of the world being denied but wouldn't be best pleased wasting it.

Comment: I would go to the village anyway.  There must be a provision for issuing some sort of document to those whose original birth records have been destroyed.  Same with the grandfather.   Do you not know where he was born?

Comment: @phoog I can easily find out where he was born(near Warsaw) but I don't think his matters so much, my cousin(different grandmother) got his without his grandfathers Yugoslavian documents as they're not needed for the citizenship. You're right I have family in the village and haven't seen them for a while so might be worth going over, could get them to ask too. I'll come back and post an answer when all is complete with what happened. Thanks for you advice

Comment: @phoog I know that seems simple its just my grandma got a passport the other year and had to go to the consulate instead of just applying by post because she couldn't get her birth certificate, they had a record of her though. There's also an issue with her DOB, she was registered on a different date than her birth and some of her documents have one date or the other, all a bit confusing!

Comment: @SamJones I would try to contact the consulate about how they would deal with such a situation, it is hard to predict, in some cases they can be incredibly strict on fulfilling the letter of the rules and in other cases it is "non c'è problema". Also asking different people can help in my experience with Italian bureaucracy if you are not satisfied with the first answer. Contacting the local comune in Italy is also something you should try, maybe with the help of your relatives there who might have better connections and command of the language?

Comment: thanks @mts i might set up a meeting, I emailed them but got a generic citizenship email back, I have been to the consulate near me before in manchester UK with my grandma, and it was 2 elderly local italian volunteers so who knows what answers they will give me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your grandmother’s civil registration birth at the local registrar’s office (anagrafe) were damaged or destroyed, a copy would have been sent to the procura della repubblica in the provincial capital, in the repository or archive of the tribunale, the district court.

First, find out whether your nona’s village was part of a larger area, where records would have been kept in a nearby town. If it is or was, you may be able to find her records in there. The discrepancy in dates might be explained by when the birth was registered, usually does within several days of birth or baptism. Baptism date is usually part of the civil birth record.

There is also Stato di famiglia, unique to Italy, which is a record of each family which has births, marriages, deaths, emigration, and is updated. These are maintained and updated by the commune.

You can look, for free, in [Family Search](https://familysearch.org/search) which does have Italian civil registration historical records from many communes and provinces. Derived from state archives, many cover the time period you need. If not the actual record, an annual index may help narrow your search. (I have no affiliation, used it for family geneology.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Managed to contact a place in Avellino(largest town near the village) and got my cousin who lives nearby to go! They have record of her birth, so ill go from there :)

Comment: @SamJones well done; my grandfather was from Mugnano del Cardinale, 20km from Avellino; perhaps we're cugini :D

Comment: Maybe we are somewhere in the tree haha, thats 40km from my grandmas village, Montaperto. Such an amazing area in those mountains!